# Preg_match doesn't work right

Tags: php, preg-match

I have spent a while to search around the internet but still couldn't find out why my script didn't work :(

Here is my string ($title) which I need to check

```
Nanatsu no Taizai – Chương 071: Tồn tại trong bóng đêm
```

And and list of regular expression I used but always returned false

```
"/^([a-z\ ]+)[\-]{1,}/i"

"/^([a-z\ ]+)[\ ]{0,1}[\-]{1,}/i"

"/^([a-z\ ]+)[\-]{1,}/ui"
```

And the code I used is

```
preg_match($regex,$title,$matches)
```

Please help me . Thank you in advance.

Comment: What value are you trying to match?

Comment: Thank you for replying . I tried to match "Nanatsu no Taizai –"

Comment: Problem with your patterns is because you match only lower case letters `a-z` thile it should be `a-zA-Z`

Comment: I used "/i" . Doesn't it take effect in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this works for you

```
$t = "Nanatsu no Taizai - Chương 071: Tồn tại trong bóng đêm";

preg_match('/(.*) - (.* [0-9]{1,}:) (.*)/i', $t, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Nanatsu no Taizai - Chương 071: Tồn tại trong bóng đêm
    [1] => Nanatsu no Taizai
    [2] => Chương 071:
    [3] => Tồn tại trong bóng đêm
)
```

Better?

Comment: I used this regular expression to test after I found an error in my code. I used this regular expression to match some certain situations of titles on my site so I really can't used regex in your answer because it will match other titles too. ex : "Yankee-kun - Mega-chan"

Comment: the `i` flag serves no purpose in the `(.*)\-` pattern... besides, if the `-` char is the delimiter, how about using `explode` or `strtok`?

Comment: neonoxGER : I can't use strrpos because my post title can be "Gintama - Bài học 458 : Bí ẩn - giấu sau màn đêm"

Comment: Is there any character, which is always present that it is possible to say "hey, here is the end of the title"? e.g. is "Something 123:" always in the middle? code updated.

Comment: @neonoxGER : We have only a format of title : <Name of comic> - (Chapter|Chap|Chương|Bài học|Tập)<chap number> : <chap title> . Then we convert that certain format to [<Name of comic>](Chapter|Chap|Chương|Bài học|Tập)<chap number>.We also post a lot of other post as manga news , our group news , manga fanart ,...

Comment: Yeah it works now. Thank you so much . I will edit it a little to use for my situations :D

Answer (score 4):

If you're just trying to extract everything up to the first `-`, the best way to do that is not to use a regular expression at all. [strtok](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) and [trim](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php), might be ideal for you:

```
$result = trim(strtok($title, '-'));
```

If you want the result to include the `-` then, you can do:

```
$result = strtok($title, '-') . '-';
```

Comment: Yeah that is a good way and thank you for replying too . But this regular expression is used for test . My true expression is used to match "Nanatsu no Taizai – Chương 071" and transfrom to "[Nanatsu no Taizai]Chương 071" and match also "Yankee-kun to Mega-chan - Bài học 458" to transform to "[Yankee-kun to Mega-chan]Bài học 458" . Can you help me find a way with strtok and trim please?

Comment: @Paulpro : I though about strrpos before but I ended up with preg_match . Because my post title might be "Gintama - Chương 458 : Bí ẩn - giấu sau màn đêm"

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [Unicode character properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php#regexp.reference.unicode), find your language from the table and use it like **\p{Thai}**

Comment: to bad OP is matching Vietnamese, not Thai

Comment: Sorry I use Vietnamese